# 2D Array stream reduce in java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, reduce

I'm new to using streams in java and I have a question on using streams.
I have a double[][] in which i want to perform the summation of elements, for it I've written the following approach similar to C#Linq, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Arrays.stream(myArray).reduce(0,(acc, i) -> acc + Arrays.stream(i).sum());
```

The error is that acc seems to be a double[], so it can't perform double[]+double.
In C#Linq the accumulator is assumed to be the same type as the seed(0 in this case). What am I missing here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the signature of `reduce`, the type of the identity has to be the type of the stream's elements. Which would be `double[]` in this case. That would also give `acc` the type of `double[]`.

There is an overload where you can supply an accumulator of a different type, but you also need to pass a combiner, to combine 2 accumulators.

You can do this:

```
double result = Arrays.stream(myArray)
    .reduce(0D, (acc, i) -> acc + Arrays.stream(i).sum(), Double::sum);
```

Where `0D` is a `double` literal, and `Double::sum` is used to combine 2 accumulators.

Alternatively, it might be more convenient to do this:

```
double result = Arrays.stream(myArray)
    .flatMapToDouble(DoubleStream::of)
    .sum();
```

Comment: flatMap is the cleanest approach.

Comment: I’d prefer `Arrays.stream(myArray) .flatMapToDouble(Arrays::stream) .sum();` as this is not a varargs use case. And `Arrays::stream` is even shorter than `DoubleStream::of`…